# Minikube K8S dashboard behind Oauth2 getting redirect uri mismatch error (github auth)

Tags: kubernetes, github, oauth-2.0, oauth, proxy

I have Minikube local cluster , and i'm trying to secure (for learning purpose) simple app using Oauth2 Proxy.

I used this manual to create simple hello world app.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

and i run `minikune tunnel` to serve all the ingresses with localhost/127.0.0.1.

before installing the Ouath2 proxy I was able to access the ingress through the web (URL --> http://localhost.hello)

**Ingress.yaml** (before adding all the annotation that required to use Oauth2 proxy)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: localhost.hello
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

i added in my /etc/host `127.0.0.1 localhost.hello` , so I able to browse to localhost.hello and im getting response.

Now i tried to install using this manual Oauth2 proxy to authenticate with GitHub before accessing the application
https://klaushofrichter.medium.com/minikube-and-oauth2-a2a383f4d531

A. I created in GitHub Application in the "Developer Settings"

1. Client ID: Iv1.f609786xxxxxx
2. Client secrets: *****6435d4aa
3. Homepage URL: http://localhost.hello
4. Callback URL: http://localhost.hello/oauth2/auth

B. Installed Oauth2 Proxy with this yaml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    oauth2-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-deploy
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      oauth2-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        oauth2-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=github
        - --email-domain=*
        - --upstream=file:///dev/null
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          value: Iv1.f60978xxxxxxx
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          value: 9b1202c5ee493xxxxxxxxxxxx
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          value: 6MRKlAxxxxxxxxxxxx
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    oauth2-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-service
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    oauth2-app: oauth2-proxy
    
--- 

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-ingress
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - localhost.hello
    secretName: myapp-tls
  rules:
  - host: localhost.hello
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /oauth2
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: oauth2-service
              port:
                number: 4180
```

and i changed my ingress.yaml to

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: \
      "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: \
      "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"    
  name: ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: localhost.hello
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

now when i'm accessing to http://localhost.hello/oauth2 , im getting the Oauth2 Proxy page , and im clicking on the Sign in with GitHub button , then it forward me to the logibn page of GitHub , and after writing my Email and Password it forward me again to the Oauth2 Proxy page with the login with GitHub and the url is

https://localhost.hello/oauth2?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=7syo4hQg2c6jH3MtZB7fAbVd-gb9QMkVkP5AV0hMJ1Y%3A%2Foauth2%3Ferror%3Dredirect_uri_mismatch%26error_description%3DThe%2Bredirect_uri%2BMUST%2Bmatch%2Bthe%2Bregistered%2Bcallback%2BURL%2Bfor%2Bthis%2Bapplication.%26error_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdocs.github.com%252Fapps%252Fmanaging-oauth-apps%252Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%252F%2523redirect-uri-mismatch%26state%3DylgQC7HFfbrGi_D2ia_xVbMpJC6f8sHpL3vZX4EXqoU%253A%252Foauth2%253Ferror%253Dredirect_uri_mismatch%2526error_description%253DThe%252Bredirect_uri%252BMUST%252Bmatch%252Bthe%252Bregistered%252Bcallback%252BURL%252Bfor%252Bthis%252Bapplication.%2526error_uri%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fdocs.github.com%25252Fapps%25252Fmanaging-oauth-apps%25252Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%25252F%252523redirect-uri-mismatch%2526state%253Dr7k_LTlhjjnYPSdzpJZu2p3S7GVi2zurfQMXWKeBzTo%25253A%25252Foauth2%25253Ferror%25253Dredirect_uri_mismatch%252526error_description%25253DThe%25252Bredirect_uri%25252BMUST%25252Bmatch%25252Bthe%25252Bregistered%25252Bcallback%25252BURL%25252Bfor%25252Bthis%25252Bapplication.%252526error_uri%25253Dhttps%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fdocs.github.com%2525252Fapps%2525252Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2525252Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2525252F%25252523redirect-uri-mismatch%252526state%25253D005J_mmCBPEuFp3pVc04cu1bg5dtOjDnJdZrF6MIlao%2525253A%2525252Foauth2

- i tried to change the "Callback URL" in GitHub setting from http://localhost.hello/oauth2 to http://localhost.hello/ but then i got 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable.

and the url was

http://localhost.hello/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=EzLboIKfuUWuiiUSL2t53Xn-WEPkfac3eG_ogJg1Yk8%3A%2Foauth2

- i tried to change the ingress annotation from

  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: 
  "https://$host/oauth2/auth"

to

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: \
  "https://$host/oauth2/"
```

and got same result , i tried a lot of "games" with that but did not managed to solve it , can someone help please ?